# How to return a YAML file as an output artifact from Lambda to CodePipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-codepipeline

I am trying to return a YAML CloudFormation template file to CodePipeline so it can be passed to CloudFormation. The file is uploaded to S3, and can be accessed and read by Lambda just fine. The issue I have is turning this file into an output artifact.

I am currently able to output the raw text as an 'Output variable', which I've confirmed from the CodePipeline Execution History in the AWS Console. In this same page there is also an artifact:

[image: S3 artifact link in CodePipeline Execution History]

However this link takes me to an error in S3, leading me to believe the artifact is never actually populated in any way.

[image: Failed S3 artifact]

This the Lambda function I have at the moment:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk')
var s3 = new AWS.S3();
var codepipeline = new AWS.CodePipeline();

exports.handler = (events, context) => {

  const params = {
    Bucket: 'myBucket',
    Key: 'myFile.yml'
  };
  
  s3.getObject(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      // Handling
    } else {
        var yamlString = data.Body.toString('utf-8');
        var params = {
          jobId: jobId,
          outputVariables: {
            s3Artifact: file
          }
        };

        codepipeline.putJobSuccessResult(params, function(err, data) {
          if(err) {
            context.fail(err);      
          } else {
            context.succeed(message);      
          }
        });
        return;
    }
  });

}
```

What confuses me is that CodePipeline clearly allows me to specify an output artifact for this Lambda function, yet I cannot work out how to do so.

[image]

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately it seems I was going about this the wrong way. I changed the pipeline to have only an S3 source action and have it be triggered by a custom CloudWatch event for when a new image is pushed to ECR. I then manually disabled the S3 event created by CodePipeline so that only an ECR push triggers a deployment.

[See more here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64543156/4839600)