# AWS Codepipeline with multiple input sources. Only want to trigger it with one of them

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

Anyone run into this issue where you have a Codepipeline with 2 input sources. Say, two s3 buckets, and you want to run the buildspec off the second input source, but you only want to trigger the pipeline on the 1st input source?  I don't want it to trigger if there are updates on the 2nd bucket.

Anyway I can prevent that? Or even prevent anything from being run in the buildspec if the 2nd bucket gets updated?

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64542844/is-it-possible-to-order-source-actions-in-codepipeline/64543156#64543156

Answer (score 0):

Do not add the Second S3 Bucket as a source to your CodePipeline. Instead, "s3 cp" the files from this bucket in a CodeBuild action to gather the files from this bucket and use them in the way intended.

A CI/CD pipeline is supposed to run when code changes, the fact that you dont want the pipeline to run on second source means this is more like a helper code that just needs to be there for build etc. and thus should be just provisioned while the pipeline is running using a copying mechanism like "git clone" or "s3 cp".